# PyMongo - Match by one nested field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am wondering how is it possible to perform complex queries in PyMongo API in order. I've got a database and I want to retrieve data. Database feature are `{id, username, ...}`, id contains `{uid, timestamp}`. I want to perform queries checking the specific `uid`.  I've tried something like:

```
db = client.test_database
db = client['trendSetters']
collection = db.test_collection
collection = db["cms_users_features"]
result =  collection.find_one()

for col in collection.find({"_id": {"uid": 702993}}):
    print col
```

EDIT

```
for col in collection.find({"_id": {"uid": 702993, "timestamp":1393554289813 }}):
    print col
```

If I add `timestamp` I can perform my query. How is it possible to do so, without adding `timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the nested field by adding a dot between a parent field name and a nested field name:
`parent_field.child_field`

This is the solution:

```
for col in collection.find({"_id.uid": 702993}):
    print col
```